# rpush notification, saves notification but not sending. Ionic receive message Notification received

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails-4, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-pushplugin

Are there any documentations regarding the data field of the Push Notification message i mean n.data { }. what does it mean?

I seem to be having the same issue as well

This is my code

```
n = Rpush::Apns::Notification.new
n.app = Rpush::Apns::App.find_by_name("Loanstreet Partners")
n.device_token = @user_auth_token.device_token # 64-character hex string
n.alert = "New Case Submission: " + la.case_code
n.data = { foo: :bar }
n.badge = 1
n.save!

Rpush.push
Rpush.apns_feedback
```

In my rpush_notifications table, i see the notification created but in my rpush_feedback it is empty. not sure why it doesn't get sent. Anyone has a clue?

I don't get any error or anything as well. So I'm sort of confused.

I do however get a Notification received from Ionic log but i dont see any notification.